# Spark standalone mode not distributing job to other worker node

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a spark job in standalone mode. I have configured my worker node to connect to master node. They are getting connected successfully, but when I am running the job on spark master the job is not getting distributed. I keep on getting the following message-

> WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources;
>   check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have
>   sufficient resources

I have tried to run the job as local on the worker node and its running fine which means resources are available. Also the spark master-ui is showing that the worker has accepted the job.Password less ssh is enabled in both master and worker node to and fro.  I feel it might be some firewall issue or may be spark driver port is not opened. My worker node logs show-

> 16/03/21 10:05:40 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command:
>   "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java" "-cp"
>   "/mnt/pd1/spark/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/sbin/../conf/:/mnt/pd1/spark/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.5.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/mnt/pd1/spark/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar:/mnt/pd1/spark/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/mnt/pd1/spark/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar"
>   "-Xms8192M" "-Xmx8192M" "-Dspark.driver.port=51810"
>   "-Dspark.cassandra.connection.port=9042" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
>   "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend"
>   "--driver-url"
>   "akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.0.1.192:51810/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler"
>   "--executor-id" "2" "--hostname" "10.0.1.194" "--cores" "4" "--app-id"
>   "app-20160321100135-0001" "--worker-url"
>   "akka.tcp://sparkWorker@10.0.1.194:39423/user/Worker"

Executor at worker nodes shows the following log in *stderr*-

> 16/03/21 10:13:52 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started 16/03/21
>   10:13:52 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting 16/03/21 10:13:52 INFO
>   Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses
>   :[akka.tcp://driverPropsFetcher@10.0.1.194:59715] 16/03/21 10:13:52
>   INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'driverPropsFetcher' on port
>   59715.

Comment: you need a resource manager, if you run in standalone mode alone, the job won't be distributed.

Comment: Spark standalone mode is a cluster manager. I am running my job on another cluster with 3 worker and 1 master node and its working fine. I feel it might be some firewall issue. How can I figure out which spark driver port is being used.

Comment: Another way for this to happen, is asking for executor memory size bigger than the RAM on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Many people have the issue when setting up new clusters. If you can find spark slaves in the web UI but they are not accepting jobs, there is a high chance that the firewall is blocking the communication. Take a look at my other answer: [Apache Spark on Mesos: Initial job has not accepted any resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919906/apache-spark-on-mesos-initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources):

> While most of other answers focuses on resource allocation (cores, memory) on spark slaves, I would like to highlight that firewall could cause exactly the same issue, especially when you are running spark on cloud platforms.
>
> If you can find spark slaves in the web UI, you have probably opened the standard ports 8080, 8081, 7077, 4040. Nonetheless, when you actually run a job, it uses SPARK_WORKER_PORT, spark.driver.port and spark.blockManager.port which by default are randomly assigned. If your firewall is blocking these ports, the master could not retrieve any job-specific response from slaves and return the error.
>
> You can run a quick test by opening all the ports and see whether the slave accepts jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can specifiy a specific driver port within the Spark context:

```
spark.driver.port  = "port"
val conf = new SparkConf().set("spark.driver.port", "51810")
```

PS: When manually starting the spark worker on the worker machine and connect it to the Master, you don`t need any further passless authentication or similar between master and spark. This would only be necessarry if you use the Master for starting all slaves (start-slaves.sh). So this shouldn`t be a problem.

Comment: I am unable to telnet to the 51810 port on the driver machine from worker node, is this the issue then? I have also added executor logs and worker logs in the problem description.

Comment: According to the Spark config, the default value for the driver port is "random". Therefore I would assume, that you first need to set this as specific port in the config, did you do that already? Additionally, the master system should open a port when launching the driver, did you have a look at netstats of the master system? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html