# Apache Spark and Mesos running on a single node

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, mesos

I am interested in testing Spark running on Mesos. I created a Hadoop 2.6.0 single-node cluster in my Virtualbox and installed Spark on it. I can successfully process files in HDFS using Spark.

Then I installed Mesos Master and Slave on the same node. I tried to run Spark as a framework in Mesos using [these instructions](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html). I get the following error with Spark:

> WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources;
>   check  your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have
>   sufficient resources

Sparkshell is successfully registered as a framework in the Mesos. Is there anything wrong with using a single-node setup? Or whether I need to add more Spark worker nodes?

I am very new to Spark and my aim is to just test Spark, HDFS, and Mesos.

Comment: Why do you want to use Mesos in first place for spark, when hadoop already comes with yarn.

Comment: I already have a OpenStack Cluster with Mesos and different frame works.. I need a shared hdfs file system in that environment with frame work to process the files in the hdfs.. Right now iam just testing spark on mesos..

Comment: how many CPUs and memory did you give to the virtualbox instance?

Answer (score 0):

If you have allocated enough resources for spark slaves, the cause might be firewall blocking the communication. Take a look at my other answer:

[Apache Spark on Mesos: Initial job has not accepted any resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35919906/apache-spark-on-mesos-initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources)